# Syncing Google Accounts with Windows 10

Tags: sync, gmail, windows-10, google-calendar, google-accounts

I recently upgraded to Windows 10. I am trying to add my Google Calendar to the native Calendar app and my Gmail to the native mail app. I click on "Add Account" and then "Google" but nothing happens. It loads for a second and then shows the same "Add Account" screen. I have scoured the web to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reset Windows 10 (hold down shift while restarting and press troubleshoot and then reset). This will wipe you're entire OS so be careful.